# Nested for-loop and appending to empty objects

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am providing values to a website filter In order to generate different html which l parse. I want to save each page source to a different Python object in order to distinguish the data. I have a list of empty objects which l will append to. parsing page source,and want to save each page source to its own Python object, which is itself in a list. In this way

The challenge is how to append the td elements from a particular html source, to the particular empty object in the list. I need to store html source at each iteration, in a separate object, which is itself found in a list.

I will simplify my example:

```
years = ['2015', '2016]
weeks = ['1', '2']
store = [[], [], [], []]
```

This gives me 4 sets of html source that I need to capture:

```
for y in years:
   for w in weeks:
```

#I will use y and w in webdriver.select to provide values for web page filter
I will then use BS to copy page source for each iteration:

```
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

And then iterate through the particular page source to extract td elements:

```
counter = 0     
for el in soup.find_all('td'):
```

to provide index for store list in order to append td elements to separate empty objects

```
for el in soup.find_all('td'):
        store[counter].append(el.get_text())
counter = counter + 1
```

Strip the element of html characters, and add to counter to move to the next object in the store list.

But the result is that all the td elements get appended to first object in the list instead of each html source having its own object. What am I missing?

Would it better to somehow use map function?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
counter=counter+1
```

is not within the for loop.

You need to indent it at the same level as the previous line, so that counter is incremented each time around the loop